# Limit problem 1

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f: D \to \mathbb R$ has a limit at $x_0$. Prove that $|f|: D\to\mathbb R$ has a limit at $x_0$ and that $\lim_{x\to x_0} |f(x)| = |\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)|$.

Here is what I have tried. If it is not correct please explain me what is the problem and give me the correct way of solving such question.
Why I can't post a photo. I don't know latex.

Comment: You said you tried something, what have you tried?

Comment: What I tried I want to give that by uploading photo.But the site resisting me doing so by saying that I have not enough points.

Comment: Add the link then someone with reputation will post the image for you for future reference

Answer (score 3):

Let $l=\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$. That means that for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$0<|x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f(x)-l|<\varepsilon.$$ Using the inverse triangle inequality: $$||f(x)-|l||\leq |f(x)-l|$$ one has $$0<|x-x_0|<\delta\implies ||f(x)|-|l||<\varepsilon.$$ This proves that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0} |f(x)|=|l|$.